# How to check for either uppercase OR lowercase letters with a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to check if there is any occurrence of an uppercase or lowercase string in this:

### test strings

```
1a
2A
3aC
```

### js

```
const str = '1a'
/[a-z]/.test(str) //Pass
/[a-z][A-Z]/.test(str) //Fail
/[a-z]/.test(str) //Pass
```

Comment: use `i` modifier to ignore the case

Comment: `[a-z][A-Z]` only matches one lower case letter followed by one upper case letter.

Comment: Thnk you for the downvote, please could you provide me with some information as to why you have closed this so I can improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[a-z]` means 1 lowercase letter. `[A-Z]` means 1 uppercase letter. `[a-z][A-Z]` means 1 lowercase letter followed by 1 uppercase letter. `[a-zA-Z]` means 1 lowercase or uppercase letter.

To check for "3aC" you might want `[0-9][a-zA-Z]+`. The "+ means one or more lowercase or uppercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there are some edge cases you are worried about....

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

should work